# Map a key on a terminal buffer whose corresponding job is already finished

Tags: terminal, autocmd, terminal-buffer

## The context

I have mapped `<c-p>` in terminal mode so that it deletes the terminal buffer where the cursor is. The way I've created this mapping is presented below

```
tnoremap <c-p> <c-w>:bd!<CR>
```

This mapping works when opening a terminal (by executing `:term`) or when executing `:term {command}` and when the `{command}` is still being executed.

If the job is finished, pressing `<c-p>` does not execute the mapped command.

Because of this, I had to find a way to create that same effect taking into consideration that mappings created with the `:tmap` command don't work when the job on a terminal buffer is finished.

I first thought in this command (see below), but I don't want `<c-p>` to be mapped in normal mode (this is explained by the fact that my main goal was to only create it for terminal buffers through the `tmap` command. Otherwise I wouldn't have post this question.)

```
nnoremap <c-p> <c-w>:bd!<CR>
```

Since I dont wan't this mapping to be created for all buffers, I tried to accomplish that with this command (whose idea was retrieved from [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/8Jr5SV6_ja8)).

```
au BufWinEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | nnoremap <buffer> <c-p> <c-w>:bd!<CR> | endif
```

However, pressing `<c-p>` didn't result in anything. I tried to troubleshot this and found out that the `BufWinEnter` is not the appropiate autocommand event, since it seems that when the `:term {command}` is executed, that `autocmd` is triggered but at that time the `&buftype` variable is not yet set.

## The question

How can I map `<c-p>` so that it executes `<c-w>:bd!<cr>` on those buffers that were opened with the `:term {command}` and whose job is already finished, without making `<c-p>` to be always mapped?

Note that this would be accomplished if we were to find an appropiate autocommand event which is triggered when the `&buftype` variable is already set because thus this mapping would work and wouldn't make `<c-p>` to be always mapped to that command.

```
au BufWinEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | nnoremap <buffer> <c-p> <c-w>:bd!<CR> | endif
```

## Additional information

The following minimal `vimrc` might help you to troubleshot this problem

```
set nocompatible

fun! P()
    echom '&buftype is: "' . &buftype . '"'
endfun

" Execute `:term ls` and you will see that the echoed message prints an empty
" `&buftype`.
autocmd BufWinEnter * call P()

" Try pressing this on a terminal whose job is finished (open one " with `:term
" ls`). You will notice that it doesn't execute the mapped command.
tnoremap <c-p> <c-w>:bd!<cr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
autocmd TerminalOpen * nnoremap <buffer> <c-p> :bdelete!<CR>
```

Note that I've used `<buffer>` to keep it local to the terminal; also, in normal mode, you don't need `<C-w>` before `:`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Although i scrolled through all the autocommands events, I didn't catch that one.

Comment: @R.Morales I got lucky :) I did `/term`

Comment: For this to work you need to have at least version 8.1 since the `TerminalOpen` event is not present in version 8.0.